# Is this a normal system log?

Tags: usb, windows, process, log, malware

I started a topic about my worries that I have a rootkit on my computer. I once again made a bootable USB with Ubuntu. On VirtualBox I had no errors, installation went fine. On bootable USB, it had some errors and didn't install Ubuntu. My timezone in Windows is switched. I saved a `sys.log` and removed the USB drive. Could you tell me if this is a normal system log? Why is my time in Windows switched (there is no way to fix it other than changing timezone.)

[log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23309105/)

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me.

To scan a log search for 'error' in it. There are a few but yours are benign.